# Dose phpMyAdmin works without config.inc.php?

Tags: phpmyadmin

I'm using Windows server 2008 R2, nginx, php7, MySQL 5.7.

I manually configured them and decided to install phpMyAdmin.

But no configuration needed after extracting phpMyAdmin files into `c:\nginx\html\phpMyAdmin` folder. It means that I didn't edit `config.inc.php`. When I enter the address `http://localhost/phpMyAdmin` in browser, the phpMyAdmin login page loaded correctly and after login via MySQL root password, there didn't any ERROR occur!

Now here is my question:

Does phpMyAdmin works without `config.inc.php`? And is this Safe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html):

> This file only needs to contain the parameters you want to change from their corresponding default value

If you don't want to change anything from the default, then you don't need to have anything in it, and it doesn't need to exist.